# Unable to plot linear regression using

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, linear-regression

I am trying to use plot_linear_regression method to plot linear regression. However, I am getting an error regarding the dimensions. I know there are many similar questions already answered and I tried implementing all of them but in vain. So, please if you couldn't solve it, at least don't mark it as duplicate question.
My query is simple. I am trying to visualize linear regression. My dataset comprises of two columns 1st is 'sqft_living' and the other is 'price'. I am trying to predict price based on 'sqft_living'. However, I am getting an error regarding dimensions. I tried many ways by converting it into numpy array and similar other manipulations but in vain. Please look into it. Any help will be highly appreciated

My query is simple. I am trying to visualize linear regression. My dataset comprises of two columns 1st is 'sqft_living' and the other is 'price'. I am trying to predict price based on 'sqft_living'. However, I am getting an error regarding dimensions. I tried many ways by converting it into numpy array and similar other manipulations but in vain. Please look into it. Any help will be highly appreciated

```
from mlxtend.plotting import plot_linear_regression
from scipy.stats import pearsonr
X = poly1_data.iloc[:, 0].values.reshape(-1, 1)  # values converts it into a numpy array
Y = poly1_data.iloc[:, 1].values.reshape(-1, 1)  # -1 means that calculate the dimension of rows, but have 1 column
X = X.astype(float)
Y = Y.astype(float)

intercept, slope, corr_coeff = plot_linear_regression(X,Y)
plt.show()
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-95-6e144511f4bc> in <module>
      6 Y = Y.astype(float)
      7 
----> 8 intercept, slope, corr_coeff = plot_linear_regression(X,Y)
      9 plt.show()

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mlxtend\plotting\plot_linear_regression.py in plot_linear_regression(X, y, model, corr_func, scattercolor, fit_style, legend, xlim)
     75         x_min, x_max = xlim
     76 
---> 77     y_min = model.predict(x_min)
     78     y_max = model.predict(x_max)
     79 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\base.py in predict(self, X)
    211             Returns predicted values.
    212         """
--> 213         return self._decision_function(X)
    214 
    215     _preprocess_data = staticmethod(_preprocess_data)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\base.py in _decision_function(self, X)
    194         check_is_fitted(self, "coef_")
    195 
--> 196         X = check_array(X, accept_sparse=['csr', 'csc', 'coo'])
    197         return safe_sparse_dot(X, self.coef_.T,
    198                                dense_output=True) + self.intercept_

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    543                     "Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if "
    544                     "your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) "
--> 545                     "if it contains a single sample.".format(array))
    546             # If input is 1D raise error
    547             if array.ndim == 1:

ValueError: Expected 2D array, got scalar array instead:
array=232.0.
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

I want to plot a scatter plot with best fit line on it using linear regression.

Comment: Check the shape of your `X and Y` variables. Looks like it was a single row of elements and you have indexed it to select a single element. Add the `shape` of `X and Y` if possible.

Comment: ````print(X.shape)
print(Y.shape)````
(9761, 1)
(9761, 1)
This is the shape of X and Y respectively